# akka-http + spray-json client side json marshalling

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-http, spray-json

I could find numerous examples on how to have an akka-http server easily marshal a response entity represented by a case class, by just mixing in SprayJsonSupport/DefaultJsonProtocol, providing a jsonFormat in implicit scope, and using the *complete* directive in the routing DSL. Neat!

However, i'd like to do something similar on the client side as well. I'm using the host-level API -provided connection pool flow ( clientFlow = Http.cachedHostConnectionPool ) to emit an (HttpRequest->context(T)) tuple like so:

```
(Source.single(request -> context)
.via(clientFlow)
.runWith(Sink.head).flatMap {
  case (Success(r: HttpResponse), c: T) => Future.successful(r)
  case (Failure(f), c: T) => Future.failed(f)
}, context)
```

the HttpRequest object is created via one of it's apply() methods

```
HttpRequest(
        method = HttpMethods.POST,
        uri = "/uri",
        entity = HttpEntity(contentType, """{"iWish":"i was an object"}"""))
```

on the server side, with the routing DSL ( with the right traits mixed in and jsonFormat for SomeCaseClass in implicit scope ) this looks something like:

```
complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, SomeCaseClass(iWish = "i was an object"))
```

q: is there anything on the client-side APIs/DSLs that allow me to hide marshalling in a similar manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have something like the following (if your `Format`s are in scope)

```
Marshal(yourObject).to[RequestEntity].map { entity =>
  HttpRequest(
    method = HttpMethods.POST,
    uri = "/uri",
    entity = entity)
}
```

(further reading [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/common/marshalling.html#Using_Marshallers))

Comment: i'm not sure how i missed this - the test case in the doc seems a bit unclear to me - i think i was expecting the HttpEntity to have to wrap around the case class instance vs the marshaller ( correctly ) producing the entire entity, content type included, instead. Thanks!